# Is it possible to use sharp-snmp to manage Access points

Tags: wifi, sharp-snmp

I want to discover all wifi clients in wifi area. I want to use sharp-snmp or any
code that configure the access point to send probe request perodically and then I want to read probe response and get the information about the Wi-fi clients(mobile and laptop)

My Question:
Is it possible to use C# or any programing langauge to access the access point 
and do what I want?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I found that I am able to do access and program the access-points by using the open source framware like OpenWRT  which is linux base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best way to access and program access-point is by using the open source firmware like OpenWRT. It is a Linux base distribution.there are a cheap device can be use such as linksys WRT.